# Missing sodium extension - wampserver

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, libsodium, sodium

I'm using wampserver 3.2.5 , trying to install package need sodium extension
i turned it and checked php.ini it not commented and then restarted all service [Soduim extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1j16.png)

But i still have this issue

```
Missing following extensions: 'sodium'
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably checked the wrong `php.ini` there are 2 one for use with Apache and the other for use with the PHP CLI.

First, upgrade to WAMPServer 3.2.7 See [The WAMPServer backup repo for that](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) or go to SourceForge if you like. It is always good to keep up to date, the WAMPServer update will not effect the versions of APache/PHP/MySQL/mariaDB etc etc that you have currently got installed and configured

Now all you have to do to activate sodium within the Apache environment is use the `wampmanager` menus like this

1. Left click the wampmanager icon in the system area

[image]

2. check the `sodium` extension, if it does not have a green tick beside it, click the word `sodium` and that will cause the correct `php.ini` to be amended and Apache will be restarted automatically.

You should now have the `sodium` extension loaded.

You can check this by clicking `localhost` in the menu and then you check the `loaded extensions` to see if sodium is now listed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ext-sodium in WAMP Sever.

Open command line and type: `php --ini` to check the path of the php.ini being used by cli. Open the php.ini file and uncomment the extension=sodium line.

```
;extension=sodium
```

to

```
extension=sodium
```